# How to parse decimal values correctly?

Tags: parsing, antlr

I'm using ANTLR with Presto grammar in order to parse SQL queries.
I'm having an issue with parsing a decimal number. I've the following definitions:

```
number
    : decimalValue  #decimalLiteral
    | DOUBLE_VALUE   #doubleLiteral
    | INTEGER_VALUE  #integerLiteral
    ;

decimalValue
    : INTEGER_VALUE '.' INTEGER_VALUE?
    | '.' INTEGER_VALUE
    ;


DOUBLE_VALUE
    : DIGIT+ ('.' DIGIT*)? EXPONENT
    | '.' DIGIT+ EXPONENT
    ;


IDENTIFIER
//    :  (LETTER | '_' | DIGIT) (LETTER | DIGIT | '_' | '@' | ':' | '.')*
    :  (LETTER | DIGIT | '_' | '@' | ':' | '-' )+
    ;
```

This works ok for most cases. However, it has an issue with parsing decimal values.

```
select x/(0.3-0.2)
from table1
```

It fails to parse. The reason is that the lexer thinks "3-0" is identifier.

When I change the query to be something like:

```
select x/(0.3 - 0.2)
from table1
```

it works.

Any ideas how can I handle the original query (without, of course, causing a regression)?

Thanks,
Nir.

Comment: I don't know how to solve your problem, but `01table` is not a valid tablename in Standard SQL and probably all DBMSes besides MySQL, should be "01table"

Comment: I've edited my question. I think the table name was related to a different issue.

Comment: You should change the IDENTIFIER definition so that '-' should be last character, or first character of an identifier.  that way `0.3-0.2` will see 2 identifiers (`0.3-` and `0.2`)

Comment: but in this case I won't fetch identifiers like- "ta-ble" which are valid ones.

Comment: You’ve discovered why numerals aren’t allowed as the initial character of an identifier: it makes parsing harder.

Comment: I don't think this is a SQL issue.  You would have an issue parsing numeric expressions, and that has nothing to do with the goals for your parsing.

Comment: Try adding in a semantic predicate in your lexer rule after the '-'.

Comment: @kaby76 - not sure I follow. Can you give an example?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/predicates.md. In the predicate, you're going to have to look forward and backward and decide whether you are lexing an IDENTIFIER (return true) or DOUBLE_VALUE (return false) at the '-'. E.g., for 0.3-0.2, the text is 0.3 and you are now at a '-'. The sem. pred. is called. Look forward (0.2), and you see that 0.2 is a number, so return false. If it was 0.3-var, you have to decide if that's a num minus var, or an entire id. If you see ta-ble, the text in the sem. pred. is "ta", so you know it can't be a number. So, return true.

Comment: @kaby76- this looks very useful. I'll try that. thanks.

Comment: One problem with sem. pred. is that it is target-specific language code. That makes your grammar less portable to other targets. One trick is to try to make the code a method call, and shovel the predicate implementation in the method.

Comment: well, I think I can live with this downside for now.